# Building a Chainlink node for a new blockchain, connection failure with error near "INCLUDE error running migration"

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, blockchain

Trying to build a new Chainlink node for a new blockchain (in my case, Alaya), however, I got an error message like this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_pipeline_task_runs_optimise_find_results ON pipeline_task_runs (pipeline_run_id);
gormigrate.v1@v1.6.0/gormigrate.go:364 rows_affected=0 time=0.016681839.  2020-12-10T10:04:03Z [FATAL] Unable to initialize ORM: pq: syntax error at or near "INCLUDE  error running migrations"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to write an external initiator (https://github.com/smartcontractkit/external-initiator) to connect to Alaya and run the Chainlink node with `ETH_DISABLED=true`.